# Haskell JSON Issue

Tags: json, haskell, bytestring, aeson

been trying to get this code working but the compiler is throwing out an error?

```
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}

 import Data.Aeson
 import Data.Text
 import Control.Applicative
 import Control.Monad
 import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
 import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)
 import GHC.Generics


data Temperatures =
Temperatures { date  :: String
     , temperature   :: Int
     } deriving (Show,Generic)


instance FromJSON Temperatures
instance ToJSON Temperatures

jsonURL :: String
jsonURL = "A JSON URL"

getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = simpleHttp jsonURL

main :: IO ()
main = do
d <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String [Temperatures])
case d of
Left err -> putStrLn err
Right ps -> print ps
```

And the error message i'm getting is

```
Main.hs:25:11:
Couldn't match type `bytestring-      0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
              with `B.ByteString'
Expected type: IO B.ByteString
  Actual type: IO
                 bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
In the return type of a call of `simpleHttp'
In the expression: simpleHttp jsonURL
In an equation for `getJSON': getJSON = simpleHttp jsonURL
```

Any suggestions of what's causing this error and how to fix it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like a build issue. I would guess that the compiler is trying to use lazy ByteStrings from two distinct packages, not sure how that could happen.

Comment: You're the second person who has suggested this could be the issue? Any ideas how I could resolve this?  Thanks.

Comment: You could try using [Cabal sandboxes](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are multiple versions of the bytestring package installed.
You can use the following command to find the bytestring packages:

ghc-pkg list bytestring

If there are more than one installed then the following could solve the problem:

ghc-pkg unregister

Or,

build with ghc --make --hide-package

Comment: Problem is it breaks aeson and a load of other packages :(

Answer (score 0):

Ah. This is known as [Cabal Hell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/Survival). Fixing it is an active area of research in the Haskell community. My suggestions would be as follows:

- If you're using Windows:

  - Install [MinGHC](https://github.com/fpco/minghc)
  - Install Stackage (Stable Hackage). You can do this globally or on a per-project basis. Here's the global way:
  - Download the [global cabal.config file](https://www.stackage.org/snapshot/lts-2.4/cabal.config?global=true).
  - Now open your global cabal config file. Mine was in `C:\Users\blauwers\AppData\Roaming\cabal` and was just called `config`.
  - Copy and paste the contents of the file your downloaded to the end of that file.
  - Your global cabal environment will now try to get packages from Stackage.
  - For extra safety, comment out the other lines in the file that start with `remote-repo`. In my case that was only `remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive`.
  - With the extra safety enabled, you'll have to [manually download and install packages](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/How_to_install_a_Cabal_package) that are not on Stackage.
- If you're using Linux: I don't know where the global cabal config file is, but the process is the same.

Comment: I like the term Cabal Hell. I will give it a go and get back to you. Thanks.